# Making an image on mouseover be eliminate whitespace

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm new and just learning basic html and css. I have an image that I've tried eliminating the white space on it, but when I save it as .jpg and place it on dreamweaver the white space keeps showing up on mouseover. I believe if I save it has a .psd it should work, but dreamweaver can't locate .psd files.

So my question is how would do I go about placing an image like the one below that will remove the whitespace and won't show up when on mouseover.

Thanks!
[Example Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tEvr.png)

P.S
I searched for a similar question to mine and couldn't find one, but if there is please help me to the questions.

Comment: Are you trying to make it transparent? JPG files don't support transparency, try saving it as PNG. This has nothing to do with JavaScript, HTML or CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your image with a format which supports transparency.

Like .gif or .[png](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Transparency_of_image).